# How to identify commands ran by Ansible on a remote host in Falco context?

Tags: docker, ssh, ansible, devops, falco

I would like to know if someone has an idea about how to identify commands ran by Ansible within a remote host.

To give you more context I'm gonna describe my workflow in-depth:

- I have a scheduled job between 1 am to 6 am which runs a compliance Ansible playbook to ensure the production servers configuration are up to date and well configured, however, this playbook change some files inside the `/etc` folder.
- Besides this, I have a Falco stack which keeps an eye on what is going on the production servers and raises alerts when an event that I describe as suspicious is found (It can be a syscall/ network connection/ sensitive file editing "/etc/passwd, pam.conf, ..." etc...

So the problem I'm running through is, my playbook triggers some alerts for example:

```
Warning Sensitive file opened for reading by non-trusted program (user=XXXX user_loginuid=XXX program=python3 command=python3 file=/etc/shadow parent=sh gparent=sudo ggparent=sh gggparent=sshd container_id=host image=<NA>)
```

My question is, can we set a "flag or prefix" to all Ansible commands, which will allow me to whitelist this flag of prefix and avoid triggering my alerts for nothing.

PS: whitelisting `python3` for the user `root` is not a solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible is python tool, so the process accessing the file will be `python3`. The commands that Ansible executes are based on the steps that are in the playbook.

You can solve your problem by modifying the `falco` rules. You can evaluating the `proc.pcmdline` in falcon rule and the chain of the `proc.aname` to identify that the command was executed by the ansible process (ex. process is `python3`, parent is `sh` grandparent is `sudo`, etc.)